# Azure Functions Scoped instances are disposed and no longer available

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am receiving below error when function app is running on the run-time version "`2.0.12701.0" (FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION = ~2 in App Settings)`. As soon I change the `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION to 2.0.12673.0` in App Settings. function starts working without any code change or deployment.

Error:

> DryIoc.ContainerException : Scope disposed{no name, Parent=disposed{no
>   name, Parent=disposed{no name}}} is disposed and scoped instances are
>   disposed and no longer available.    at DryIoc.Throw.It(Int32
>   error,Object arg0,Object arg1,Object arg2,Object arg3) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 8991    at DryIoc.Scope.TryGet(Object& item,Int32 id) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 7881    at
>   DryIoc.Container.InstanceFactory.GetAndUnwrapOrDefault(IScope
>   scope,Int32 factoryId) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 1480    at
>   DryIoc.Container.InstanceFactory.GetInstanceFromScopeChainOrSingletons(IResolverContext
>   r) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 1466    at
>   DryIoc.Container.ResolveAndCacheDefaultFactoryDelegate(Type
>   serviceType,IfUnresolved ifUnresolved) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 224    at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IResolver.Resolve(Type
>   serviceType,IfUnresolved ifUnresolved) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 195    at DryIoc.Resolver.Resolve[TService](IResolver
>   resolver,IfUnresolved ifUnresolved) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 4742    at
>   DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.DryIocAdapter.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(IResolverContext
>   r) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\DryIocAdapter.cs
>   : 156    at
>   DryIoc.Registrator.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.b__0(IResolverContext
>   r) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 4541    at lambda_method(Closure ,IResolverContext )    at
>   DryIoc.Factory.<>c__DisplayClass26_1.b__2() at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 6596    at DryIoc.Scope.TryGetOrAdd(ImMap`1 items,Int32
>   id,CreateScopedValue createValue,Int32 disposalOrder) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 7840    at DryIoc.Scope.GetOrAdd(Int32 id,CreateScopedValue
>   createValue,Int32 disposalOrder) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 7825    at DryIoc.Factory.ApplyReuse(Expression serviceExpr,Request
>   request) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 6595    at DryIoc.Factory.GetExpressionOrDefault(Request request) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 6555    at DryIoc.Factory.GetDelegateOrDefault(Request request) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 6625    at DryIoc.DelegateFactory.GetDelegateOrDefault(Request
>   request) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 7731    at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IResolver.Resolve(Type
>   serviceType,Object serviceKey,IfUnresolved ifUnresolved,Type
>   requiredServiceType,Request preResolveParent,Object[] args) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 290    at lambda_method(Closure )    at
>   DryIoc.Scope.TryGetOrAdd(ImMap`1 items,Int32 id,CreateScopedValue
>   createValue,Int32 disposalOrder) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 7840    at DryIoc.Scope.GetOrAdd(Int32 id,CreateScopedValue
>   createValue,Int32 disposalOrder) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 7825    at lambda_method(Closure ,IResolverContext )    at
>   DryIoc.Container.ResolveAndCacheDefaultFactoryDelegate(Type
>   serviceType,IfUnresolved ifUnresolved) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 224    at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IResolver.Resolve(Type
>   serviceType,IfUnresolved ifUnresolved) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs
>   : 195    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.DependencyInjection.ScopedServiceProvider.GetService(Type
>   serviceType) at
>   C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\ScopedServiceProvider.cs
>   : 25    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
>   sp,Type type,Type requiredBy,Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)    at
>   lambda_method(Closure ,IServiceProvider ,Object[] )    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance[T](IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider) at
>   C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.cs
>   : 37    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance[T](IFunctionInstanceEx
>   functionInstance) at
>   C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.cs
>   : 32    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.<>c__DisplayClass1_1.<.ctor>b__0(IFunctionInstanceEx
>   i) at
>   C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.cs
>   : 20    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.Create(IFunctionInstanceEx
>   functionInstance) at
>   C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.cs
>   : 26    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.CreateInstance(IFunctionInstanceEx
>   functionInstance) at
>   C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs
>   : 44    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ParameterHelper.Initialize()
>   at
>   C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs
>   : 846    at async
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsyncCore(IFunctionInstanceEx
>   functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs
>   : 116

Changing the Function run-time version (FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION =2.0.12673.0) in App Setting from default run-time version 2.0.12701.0 fixed the issue.

This is my Function App Startup class which register dependencies.

```cs
 public class FunctionAppStartup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                                .AddJsonFile("secret.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                                .Build();

            builder.Services.Configure<ConfigurationManager>(x => config.Bind(x));
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<Contracts.IConfiguration>(resolver =>
                resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ConfigurationManager>>().Value);

            builder.Services.AddScoped<IChannelAdapter, ChannelAdapter>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<ITableStorageManager, TableStorageManager>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseContext, DatabaseContext>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IJobRepository, JobRepository>();
        }
    }
```

Expecting my function app to run on the latest run-time version instead of me targeting a minor run-time version.

Comment: Thanks for the report @SIDHU. I've created https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4989 so we can try to reproduce what you're seeing. Would you mind following up with me there?

Comment: This issue is now fixed with the latest release of azure function run-time.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5060

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fro now, you couldn't use this runtime version.

Cause even this is a latest released version, however it's not updated to production site. Please check the [release note](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases).

> Note: This release is not yet in production but will be deploying over the next few days. These release notes will be updated when it has been deployed to all production sites.

When it's updated, the official will update the note. So the latest available version is `2.0.12673`.

Comment: Thanks George. I am doing anything to target this version. my function app is automatically created using arm template and it's setting my run-time version to latest version when I am deploying my code using DevOps.

Comment: Hi George, How can I tell azure to not automatically promote latest version of run-time which is not production ready for my function app?

Comment: You mean if you set with ~2, it will be `2.0.12701.0`, if yes suppose you have to point the version manually. And if you have this problem suppose you could report this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues).

Comment: Thanks George. I have reported the issue to Azure Functions team. I don't want to set my function app to minor version then I have to manually  update it every time a new version is released.

Comment: Maybe you could tru with `latest` refer to this answer.https://stackoverflow.com/a/40332737/10383250

Comment: @SIDHU, if this could help you, please accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @SIDHU I am also facing the same kind of issue, https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/9316.

Can you please put some light on it